# youtube dl how to download all audio from a playlist

Tags: python, video, youtube, stream, youtube-dl

How would I donwload a youtube playlist and automatically convert it to mp3? what command would i use. keep in mind i am using windows cmd not linux. For instance, if i wanted to download https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l11mUSu7aeA&list=PLegw_VDN9vXQKRhktd_l7EQCRmHxsib7r all the videos here as  audio only to my computer with youtube dl what command would i use?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use. `youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 [URL]` or `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 [URL]`

Comment: can you write out the full command? everytime i do (link) --audio-format MP3 it will just download the mp4 video file

Comment: I revised the answer with all the details, it should work now.

Comment: Did it work, or are you still having this issue?

Comment: yes, it did work. Thanks a lot that was very helpful and thanks for following up on whether or not it worked: really appreciate it